# Where can I watch recorded Go games from Masters?

Tags: go, study, kifu

I think I can learn more if I see what people some kyu above me do.

I'm aware of a [related question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-do-you-recommend-to-learn-go), but I think, this one is more specific and might diverge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best place I find to watch amateur games and learn to play go is [KGS](http://www.gokgs.com/). It's a fairly friendly Go server with an emphasis on teaching. You can watch and kibbitz on games in progress, or you can look through many game records. It's also good for finding stronger players to play in teaching games, in which they review how you played afterwards.

[IGS/PandaNet](http://www.pandanet.co.jp/English/) tends to broadcast more professional games, so if you want to watch and learn from pro games, rather than higher level amateurs, that might be a good place to look. There are other Go servers as well; there's a [list](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoServers) on Sensei's Library.

If you're interested in reviewing older games, not watching live games, there are [many professional games](http://senseis.xmp.net/?GoDatabases) available for purchase or sometimes even free download, such as the ["Games of Go on Disk"](http://www.gogod.co.uk/) collection. Or if you prefer paper, you can find collections of games by master players, such as [Honinbo Shusaku](http://senseis.xmp.net/?InvincibleTheGamesOfShusaku) or [Go Seigen](http://senseis.xmp.net/?WuQingyuansCollectedGames).

Comment: Lately wbaduk had an English server added. From there you can jump to korean/chinese/japanese servers as well. On each you can find several "recent" pro games, some played on the site, some relayed on it. But I do prefer kgs+ (where pros **teach you** (usually in groups via lectures) using a nice interface. And they often teach using a Pro game as the material)

Answer (score 9):

sorry for the late answer.

The following list might be useful to others:

http://www.go4go.net/v2/modules/collection/

http://9-dan.com/

http://www.gogameworld.com/

http://www.lifein19x19.com/gogames/database1.htm

http://gokifu.com/

http://baduk4all.com/

That's enough to give you study material for a life :)